# NDSolve and WhenEvent Causing Excess Work

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, version-9

When I use the following system

```
model = {x'[t] == x[t] (1 - x[t]) - x[t] y[t], y'[t] == x[t] y[t] - y[t], x[0] == 0.5, y[0] == 0.5}
```

with the `WhenEvent`

```
perturb = WhenEvent[Mod[t, 1],
    {x[t] -> x[t], y[t] -> y[t]}
];
```

chosen to be trivial, I have what seems to be strange behavior to me, namely if I do the following integration

```
NDSolve[{model, perturb}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 10000}]
```

I get an error that the integration reached maximum steps at `t==8670.`, even though nothing is changing. If I increase the `MaxSteps` I can get it to integrate. So my question is if this is expected? The longer you integrate a system when using a `WhenEvent` the larger the `MaxSteps` you will need? I can replicate this same behavior when I use initial conditions that are on a stable equilibrium value ... so truly nothing is changing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is that event detection itself adds plenty of overhead.  We can see this by comparing this:

```
model = {x'[t] == x[t] (1 - x[t]) - x[t] y[t], 
  y'[t] == x[t] y[t] - y[t], x[0] == 0.5, y[0] == 0.5};
perturb = WhenEvent[Mod[t, 1], {x[t] -> x[t], y[t] -> y[t]}];
eventPoints = Reap[NDSolve[{model, perturb}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 10000},
  StepMonitor :> Sow[t]]][[2, 1]];
eventPoints // Length

(* Out: 18670 *)
```

To this:

```
nonEventPoints = Reap[NDSolve[model, {x, y}, {t, 0, 10000},
 StepMonitor :> Sow[t]]][[2, 1]];
nonEventPoints // Length

(* Out: 347 *)
```

We can even illustrate exactly why this would happen.

```
pts1 = {#, 0} & /@ Select[eventPoints, # < 6 &];
pts2  = {#, 1} & /@ Select[nonEventPoints, # < 6 &];
ListPlot[{pts1, pts2}, AspectRatio -> Automatic,
  Axes -> False]
```

[image]

We can see the points piled up at the events.

Comment: I see ... so since I am doing a perturbation at each time step, then that is why I am having to grow `MaxSteps` for longer output ... as I using up my "bank" near each event. I was thinking more like this was analogous to a Fortran solver that does integration a "step" at a time ... not considering the how the adaptive step size was working. Thanks!

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi I don't think that point of view is quite reasonable. The event is part of the specification of the problem, so you *have to* expect that changing it could change the computational complexity. Consider the event x[t]==0; there's no particular reason to expect that one of the interpolation points generated by the eventless equations will match that event exactly. If you want machine precision, you've got to back up and perform a `FindRoot` to figure out exactly when the event occurs.  That's quite costly.

Comment: @MarkMcClure true, but for cases that happen at regular intervals (ie `Mod[t,1]` etc) this is slightly counter intuitive until you understand your answer. In these cases the events are easy to detect ... but the way the solver is allocating effort is subtle since it is I imagine trying to ensure that possible local discontinuities are being handled correctly.

Comment: @Gabriel I certainly undertand the hope, even expectation, that event detection with `Mod[t,1]` might work better. I think the detection techniques are purely numerical, though, so while it's clear to us where they happen, they still generate a lot of extra work for the algorithm.

Comment: @MarkMcClure don't get me wrong ... your point is well taken! It would just be nice to have an extra option that would tell the maximum steps taken *between* events ... that way the user doesn't need to have to do any hand calculations on the number of time steps, and the predicted number of events to figure out how many maximum steps need to be taken. This will make the calculations much slower ... but seems like it will be a common need for these types of problems. Again I think of it the way old Fortran codes would have worked ... each call you get the maximum steps so it *naturally* scales

Comment: @Gabriel Like much of V9, the event detection could certainly be refined - and probably will be!

Comment: @MarkMcClure for sure. I love `WhenEvent` so much ... it could make me have to do a back flip each time I use it and it would still keep me coming back!

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi weird ... guess it just keeps trying!

Comment: People seem to forget that event detection has to do rootfinding and interpolation in addition to the integration proper; it should be no surprise that detecting events interferes with the normal step size selection, and thus incurs a fair amount of overhead.