# How can I get WhenEvent to recognize criterion I specify?

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

Using NDSolve I want to solve a differential equation till a quantity which is a function of the dependent variables reaches a certain value. My functions and criteria are complicated, but I am able to reproduce the error with a simple DE:

```
a[t_] := x[t]^2
NDSolve[{x'[t] == Sin[t]^2, x[0] == 0, 
   WhenEvent[a[t] == 1, "StopIntegration"]}, {x}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

Here is the error message I get:

> NDSolve::nbnum1: "The function value x[0.00205297]^2==1 is not True or False when the arguments are {0.00205297,5.40788*10^-9,4.21468*10^-6}."

Any Ideas would be great

Answer (score 9):

Need to evaluate it

```
a[t_] := x[t]^2
NDSolve[{x'[t] == Sin[t]^2, x[0] == 0, 
  WhenEvent[Evaluate[a[t] == 1], "StopIntegration"]}, {x}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

Notice the attribute `HoldAll` on the function `WhenEvent`

```
?? WhenEvent
Attributes[WhenEvent]={HoldAll,Protected}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Nasser has shown you a minimal change which will solve your problem. I still would like to add two suggestions which might make your life easier when dealing with more complicated cases:

## reformulate stopping criterion

in another [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19053/169) which might be of interest I am postulating that it often pays off to try to be as precise as possible when formulating your problem to be solved with Mathematica, and I believe this is also such a case. You are writing your stopping condition as a function of `t`, but actually it is a function of `x[t]`. It's exactly that "hiding" of the real dependence which makes the `WhenEvent` not work without the `Evaluate`. If you rewrite the stopping criterion as a function of `x[t]`, no `Evaluate` is necessary, and I think the code also reflects more correctly what the actual dependencies are:

```
a[x_] := x^2
NDSolve[{x'[t] == Sin[t]^2, x[0] == 0, 
  WhenEvent[a[x[t]] == 1, "StopIntegration"]}, {x}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

## make criterion numerically robust

while the above does work, I'm not sure whether or not the `WhenEvent` will actually work might depend on the step sizes taken by the solver: if these happen to be too large in the area where the stopping condition is met the event might be overseen. In principle, as  the symbolic form is known, `NDSolve` could be written to take such problems into account and detect the event nevertheless. The documentation of `WhenEvent` and the answer to this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16127/169) seems to indicate that this might indeed be done since version 9, but I probably wouldn't count on that: I know that the older way of doing things like that with `Method -> "EventLocator"` did not always detect such cases. It's fairly simple to rewrite the `WhenEvent` so that it will work without dependencies on such advanced event detection or step sizes for the given example, e.g.:

```
a[x_] := x^2
sol = First[
  x /. NDSolve[{x'[t] == Sin[t]^2, x[0] == 0, 
     WhenEvent[a[x[t]] >= 1, "StopIntegration"]}, {x}, {t, 0, 10}]]
```

it might, on the other hand not be necessary anymore...

Comment: I get the same error with this line (notice that phi(x,t) is my unknown function in NDSolve):

``WhenEvent[\[Phi][x, t] == 0, TsingE = t; 
 Print[TsingE]; "StopIntegration"]``

I reckon is the same error, but doesnt' go away with any of your solutions.

Comment: @usumdelphini: it is difficult to analyze what's going wrong without seeing the actual code. If the above suggestions don't help for your case I'd suggest to write a new question with giving more details, especially a working example will always help wonders to generate useful answers...

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44370/whenevent-for-several-variables?noredirect=1#comment132349_44370

See answer and comments, please. Thanks!