# WhenEvent for several variables

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve a system of nonlinear two differential equations (say, in $\theta(x,t)$ and $\phi(x,t)$ with `NDSolve`, but I want to stop the evaluation when one of the functions ($\phi(x,t)$) reaches zero, or, for instance, a certain value $\bar{\phi}$.

Because then I would like to study how, where and (of course) when this pinch-off happens.

What is the best way of doing this, in your opinion?

Putting a constraint before running `NDSolve`?

I tried with WhenEvent, adding a line  `WhenEvent[\[Phi][x, t] == 0, Plot[\[Phi][x, T], {x, 0, L}]` in the code, but it gives me

```
NDSolve::litarg:
To avoid possible ambiguity, the arguments of the dependent variable in  WhenEvent
(...)should literally match the independent variables
```

Here is the link to the shortest code I can manage to give:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4t5o53lppb2itk8/mma3.nb

Comment: Use [WhenEvent](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WhenEvent.html)

Comment: How can I deal with the fact that I have two variables? I mean, if I write WhenEvent[$\phi$[x,t]==0, Tsing=t], I don't think it would work...

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use ``Method -> {"EventLocator", "Event" -> phi[x,t]==0}] ``

Comment: `WhenEvent` is the new way to do it, introduced in v9. It should do everything that EventLocator did and more. Sorry, no time to check the details right now ...

Comment: The problem here is that the integration proceeds along the `t` axis (Mathematica uses the method of lines), so asking when `f[x,t]==0` is not a well defined question.  I guess you mean `f[x,t]==0` *for all `x`*, but that is unlikely to happen.  So the condition should probably be something else.

Comment: not exactly, I mean for any x!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What Silvia wrote about the method of lines is basically true. The problem is that `NDSolve` tries as much as possible to "hide" the specifics about the discretization procedure so you can't use something like `u[t,x]` in a `WhenEvent` for a PDE as `x` would mean "any x" and that would be inifintely many tests. But for exactly that use-case there is the possibility to get a list of values at the actual discretization points instead which makes the formulation of the desired `WhenEvent` almost trivial and quite fast. The trick is to use `"DiscretizedMonitorVariables" -> True` for the `"MethodOfLines"` method. `u[t,x]` will then in fact be a vector of as many values as the method of lines uses in the spatial direction (and I think it should handle all cases with nontrivial spatial discretizations as well):

```
NDSolveValue[{
  D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x],
  u[0, x] == 0,
  u[t, 0] == Sin[t],
  u[t, 5] == 0,
  WhenEvent[Min[u[t, x]] < -10^-4,
   tEnd = t; "StopIntegration"
   ]
  }, u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 5},
 Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "DiscretizedMonitorVariables" -> True}
 ]
```

For more information, see `tutorial/NDSolveWhenEvents#24434` in the documentation center (or search for "Avoiding Wraparound in PDEs" [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveWhenEvents.html)) and of course [`tutorial/NDSolveOverview`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolveOverview.html) is always a good place to learn about the details of `NDSolve`...

Comment: This is a true answer!

Answer (score 3):

I haven't seen your particular PDEs, but I don't think your can numerically evaluate the target functions *in* the `NDSolve` scope, as the numerical solutions (expressed as `InterpolatingFunction` objects) hasn't been constructed.

If it were me, I may consider doing the plotting afterward:

```
sol = NDSolve[{
                y''[t] == -1, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0,
                WhenEvent[
                           y[t] == 0,
                           tEnd = t; "StopIntegration"
                         ]
              }, y, {t, 0, 2}];
Plot[y[t] /. sol, {t, 0, tEnd}]
```

### Update:

I think I overlooked the question, and the real difficulty here might be related to [*the numerical method of lines*](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NDSolvePDE.html), which is the way how `NDSolve` deals with this kind of PDEs.

According to the documentation, with the NML, the directions of *boundary-value problem* are considered as *space* dimensions, and the direction of *initial-value problem* is considerd as *time* dimension. All *space* dimensions are discretized, but **the numerical integrations are only taken along the *time* dimension**. So it's many *lines* start from some points in the *space* space at *time* zero, and evolve over *time*, thus the internal integrations are all one-dimensional and **the `"StopIntegration"` action can only be taken along *time*.** This is the reason you got [the error in your comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44370/whenevent-for-several-variables/44376?noredirect=1#comment132337_44376).

One possible (and only partial) solution is specifying all *space* variables in `WhenEvent`, leaving only the *time* variable. Here is a simple demonstration:

```
Module[{sol},
       sol = NDSolve[{
                      D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x, x],
                      u[0, x] == 0,
                      u[t, 0] == Sin[t], u[t, 5] == 0,

                      (* the space variable x, i.e. #, is fixed value: *)
                      WhenEvent[u[t, #] - .1 == 0,
                                tEnd = t; "StopIntegration"
                               ]

                      },
                      u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 5}];
       Plot3D[
              Evaluate[-(#/10) + u[t, x] /. sol], {t, 0, tEnd}, {x, 0, 5},
              PlotRange -> All, 
              PlotStyle -> ColorData["Rainbow"][1 - Rescale[#, {0, 5}]], 
              Mesh -> False]
      ] & /@ Range[0, 5, .5] // 
 Show[#, AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 20, Italic, Bold] & /@ {t, x, u}), Lighting -> "Neutral"] &
```

[image: integration can only be stop along time]

Comment: It gives me always 

``NDSolve::litarg:
To avoid possible ambiguity, the arguments of the dependent variable in  WhenEvent
(...)should literally match the independent variables

I think that this might be related with having 2 independent variable``

Comment: @usumdelphini Sounds like syntax problems to me. Could you add your whole PDEs and mma code in the question?

Comment: I've just linked a minimal .nb, unfortunately I cannot do any better, but essentially I do not think it is matter of syntax, because if I remove the line "WhenEvent[...]", everything works fine.

Comment: @usumdelphini Looks like you're using mma 7 while `WhenEvent` is introduced in version 9. Sorry for the confusion... I don't have a version 7, will delete this answer soon.

Comment: I've just run this now on version 9, same error!

Comment: @usumdelphini I think you do have a syntax error: the `WhenEvent[...]` should be *inside* the `{...}`, not after.

Comment: Thanks, now it actually gives me another error (sorry to bother you so much), ``NDSolve::nbnum1: The function value InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,10.}},{4,7,0,{25},{6},0,0,0,0,Automatic},<<1>>,{Developer`PackedArrayForm,{0,<<25>>},{2.005,2.00496,2.00483,2.00462,2.00433,2.00397,<<13>>,1.99603,1.99567,1.99538,1.99517,1.99504,1.995}},{Automatic}][x]==0 is not True or False when the arguments are {0.,<<3>>,{-0.000916735,-0.000908904,-0.000885598,-0.000847226,-0.00079441,-0.00072804,-0.000649232,<<11>>,0.000649232,0.000728807,0.000795892,0.000849321,0.000888165,0.000911767,0.000919698}}. >>``

Comment: @usumdelphini I think I overlooked the real difficulty in your question! Please see my edit.

Comment: Same error, even with the #... :(